# When I receive the EEG data from the Muse monitor app the values are gibberish, how do I convert them for online analysis?

Tags: python, encoding, server, udp, osc

I have to obtain the data from the muse headset (2016 version) for online analysis, the python server code that I am using gives me total gibberish, there are no values for me to do analysis on (the output that I get is like when we open a DLL file through a text editor).

## code

```
import socket

localIP     = "192.168.1.6"

localPort   = 5005

bufferSize  = 1024


UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))

 

print("UDP server up and listening")

while(True):

    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    
    print(clientMsg)
```

The values that I should obtain are numerical values.

Comment: The data is likely to be encoded in a binary format.  We need to know what that format is to advise on how to decode it.

Comment: The messages are in OSC format

Comment: Looks like [this package](https://pypi.org/project/python-osc/) does what you want.

Comment: Also, I answered a similar question recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757258/how-do-i-decode-data-when-i-dont-know-the-specific-encoding/54761661#54761661)